# Unable to load shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern' or one of its dependencies

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods' threw an exception.

 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libOpenCvSharpExtern: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

   at OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods.redirectError(CvErrorCallback errCallback, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr& prevUserdata)

   at OpenCvSharp.Internal.ExceptionHandler.RegisterExceptionCallback()

   at OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods.LoadLibraries(IEnumerable`1 additionalPaths)

   at OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods..cctor()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods.videoio_VideoCapture_new2(String filename, Int32 apiPreference, IntPtr& returnValue)

   at OpenCvSharp.VideoCapture..ctor(String fileName, VideoCaptureAPIs apiPreference)

   at OfflineVideoAnalysis.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/OfflineVideoAnalysis/Program.cs:line 25
```

Comment: You will need to provide some more detail to encourage anyone to give you some help - posting a stack trace on its own is not very useful. What hare you trying to do? What have you tried? The stacktrace suggests running with some extra debug parameters - have you tried that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.